# How to display certain divs depending on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display specific divs depending on the date. The divs are split up by months. Only the current month and the next month should display. The code below is how I have it set up, but I know I'm missing code. I just have no idea what else to add to make this work.

NOTE: I'm trying to set it up so I don't have to call out specific div id's that way I don't have to go in every month and change the code to display the next two divs.

HTML

```
<div id="1">
  MONTH ONE CONTENT
</div>
<div id="2">
  MONTH TWO CONTENT
</div>
<div id="3">
  MONTH THREE CONTENT
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
  #1, #2, #3 {display: none;}
</style>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var date=new Date();
  var one_month = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 1);
  var two_month = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 1);

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(one_month).css('display','block');
    $(two_month).css('display','block');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The HTML Specification says ID and Name attributes must begin with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="monthContent">
    <div id="one">
      MONTH ONE CONTENT
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      MONTH TWO CONTENT
    </div>
    <div id="three">
      MONTH THREE CONTENT
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#monthContent > div {display: none;}
```

**Script**

```
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var nextMonth = month + 1;
nextMonth = nextMonth == 13 ? 1 : nextMonth;

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $( "#monthContent>div:nth-child(" + month + ")").show();
      $( "#monthContent>div:nth-child(" + nextMonth + ")").show();
  });
```

Comment: if (nextMonth > 12) {nextMonth = 1;} ?

Answer (score 0):

ID's are not allowed to start with a number, but class can.

http://jsfiddle.net/marathonman/6CwSY/

**HTML**

`<div id="months">
    <div id="m1">1</div>
    <div id="m2">2</div>
    <div id="m3">3</div>
    <div id="m4">4</div>
    <div id="m5">5</div>
    <div id="m6">6</div>
    <div id="m7">7</div>
    <div id="m8">8</div>
    <div id="m9">9</div>
    <div id="m10">10</div>
    <div id="m11">11</div>
    <div id="m12">12</div>
</div>`

**CSS**

`#months > div {
    display: none;
}`

**SCRIPT**

`var d = new Date();
//getMonth() method returns 0 to 11
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
$('#m' + (m) + ',#m' + ((m  + 1)  % 12)).show();`

thank you jeremy, updated for m 12

Comment: Hmmmm not working for me for some reason. Does this javascript have to go within a document ready or something? I renamed my id's div1, div2, etc. since you said that they can't start with a number. I also changed the #m's in the javascript to match my id names.